# how to show list items separately in output using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created one html which contains search box. After searching, I'm getting the data in list. But when I click on that I'm getting the value of all list item by using `this`

```
var text = $(this).text(); method
```

In my app, if I click on one item only it should give me only that value of list item not other. I'm making a mistake somewhere, but I don't know where.
Here is my code:

HTML

```
<ul data-role="listview" class="ui-li-icon">
    <li id="list"></li>
</ul>
```

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
function successCallback(responseObj)
{
    // alert(JSON.stringify(responseObj));
    form.reset();
    dataj=JSON.stringify(responseObj);
    len=dataj.length;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    { 
        var output = "<ul>" + responseObj.merchants[i].imageFileName+ " " + "<font size=3 color=green>"  + responseObj.merchants[i].merchantName  +  "</font>"  +"</ul>";
        $('#list').append(output);
    }
    $('#list').click(function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
        var text = $(this).text();
        alert('Index is: ' + index + ' and text is ' + text);
    });
}
```

So when I'm searching for some a item. I'm getting list of:

```
ab
abc
```

But when I clicked on it. I get value of both `ab` and `abc`. I just want only one value where I have clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//replace your click event by below code

```
$('.ui-li-icon li').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    var text = $(this).text();
    alert('Index is: ' + index + ' and text is ' + text);
});
```

Comment: thanks..i tried this and its working ..can u tell me how to refresh this list..?

Comment: recall ajax and then 
$('.ui-li-icon li').unbind('click'); 
and again attach same event

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#list').append(output);
```

I believer list is the id you are giving to list items i.e.

Now, this will confuse the browser because id should be UNIQUE and here you are giving this id to all the list items.

If you fix this, your problem should be resolved!

Or you could simply attach click event using this

```
$('.ui-li-icon li').click   //Your click event handler
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to understand what you are asking.  From what I can tell you're looking for something like this:

```
$('#list li').on('click', function(){
    alert("index: "+$(this).index() + " value: "+ $(this).text()); 
});
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jw8qz/